# I've got a error when bison compiling with option %defines "Parser.h"

Tags: bison

My Parser.y file contains below code.

```
%defines "Parser.h"
```

I've compiled this file and I've got a below error.

> $ bison Parser.y
>
> Parser.y:27.10-19: syntax error, unexpected string

So I've made this line commented.

```
//%defines "Parser.h"
```

I've compiled this file and I've got no error but It didn't make output header file.

And I've changed compile option.

> $ bison Parser.y --defines=Parser.h

It was successful but I don't want use option with "bison" command.

In other words, I want to use %defines option in bison file.

What should I do?

Sorry for pooooooor english.

Comment: post full code in order others to run your code and see the error

Comment: @pinkpanther thanks for comment but it was solved. the full code is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_bison).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `%defines` directive is supported in Bison 2.6.2.

Superficially, it appears that you are not using a sufficiently recent version of Bison and your version does not support `%defines`.  However, that seems improbable; you'd have to be using a version that's a decade or more old (the first reference in the ChangeLog to `%defines` is dated in 2001).

Another possibility is that you've not included it at an appropriate point in the grammar file.  I believe it should appear before the first `%%` that marks the start of the grammar proper.

You could try omitting the file name; if the source is Parser.y and you write a line `%defines`, the generated header is Parser.h anyway.  I'm not confident this will work, but it is worth a try.

Comment: Thanks. I've used Bison 2.3 version

Comment: I've tried Bison 2.3 on a minimal grammar with `%defines "file.h"` and it fails; the same code compiles with Bison 2.6.2.  The grammar I used was called `min.y` and had three lines: `%defines "minimal.h"`, 
`%%`, and
`info: 'a' 'b' 'c'` only.  This generated a fairly small (but definitely not minimal) file called `minimal.h` with Bison 2.6.2.  Without the file name, the `%defines` line works with Bison 2.3.